# Vim doesn't work after rvm ruby update

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, vim, rvm

I'm using rvm on ubunut 13.04. Today I updated ruby with latest 1.9.3 version.
Now, when I try to start vim I get:

`vim: error while loading shared libraries: libruby.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

`ldd $(which vim) | grep ruby` gives `libruby.so.1.9 => not found`

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: would you share any `VIM` installation link? I never used it.

Comment: What is the output of `ldd $(which vim)`?

Comment: `ldd $(which vim) | grep ruby` gives `libruby.so.1.9 => not found`

Comment: @MarcinDoliwa Ok, did you compile Vim yourself?

Comment: hmm, don't remember, how can I check it?

Comment: @MarcinDoliwa In that case; probably not. It sounds like you're doing a system wide RVM installation, which is probably not a good idea as your Vim is compiled for a specified version of Ruby if it's from the repositories. I'm no expert on RVM and the way it affects shared libraries used by Vim, but it seems that you have to either compile Vim with whatever Ruby you've installed using RVM, or don't use system wide RVM and rely on Vim+Ruby shipped in the repos of Ubuntu. But again, I can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

The Vim binaries are compiled against a particular Ruby (, Python, Perl, etc.) version. If that version vanishes, the integration is broken.

You can try to put back the required library with a link (something like `libruby.so.1.9` -> `libruby.so.1.9.3`). If that fails, you have to find a corresponding Vim version or compile Vim yourself.